# How to let the NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest perform before UITableView init

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

I have declared a Array and init it by achieve data from The Internet . I want it inited before UITableView init because it was to fill the cell of UITableView but obviously it didn't.What can I do to improve the codes
the terminal prints 
1
2
2
2
3
4
4
I want it prints 
1
4
4
2
2
2
3

HttpController.swift

```
import UIKit

protocol HttpProtocol{
    func didRecieveResults(results:NSDictionary)
}

class HttpController:NSObject{

    var delegate:HttpProtocol?

    func onSearch(url:String){
        var nsUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string:url)!
        var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: nsUrl)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {
            (response:NSURLResponse!,data:NSData!,error:NSError!)->Void in
            var jsonResult:NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! NSDictionary
            self.delegate?.didRecieveResults(jsonResult)
        })
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,HttpProtocol {
    @IBOutlet weak var tv: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var iv: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var playTime: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!

    var eHttp:HttpController = HttpController()
    var tableData:NSArray = NSArray()
    var channelData:NSArray = NSArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        eHttp.delegate = self
        eHttp.onSearch("http://www.douban.com/j/app/radio/channels")
        eHttp.onSearch("http://douban.fm/j/mine/playlist?channel=0")
        println(1)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        println(2)
        return 1//tableData.count
     }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell!{
        println(3)
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,reuseIdentifier:"douban")
      //  let rowData:NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
        cell.textLabel!.text = "hehehehe"//rowData["title"] as! String
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = "adasdasda"//rowData["artist"] as! String
        return cell
     }
    func didRecieveResults(results:NSDictionary){
        println(4)
        if (results["song"] != nil){

            self.tableData = results["song"] as! NSArray


        }else if (results["channels"] != nil){
            self.channelData = results["channels"] as! NSArray
         //   println(channelData)
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to init array before init table view, when your data array is ready - just call

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: but tableView (....numberOfRowsInSection ) must return the number of array,else it will crash

Comment: check if array is valid and if not return '0'. otherwise return array.count